# How could G-d have created the world, according to one opinion?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

A basic philosophical necessity in an Infinite Being creating a finite universe is the concept of *tzimtzum*, which is a simple enough concept that it needs no further explanation here.

What I'm wondering is, the majority opinion as recorded in Bechoros 17a is that it is *impossible* to do *tzimtzum*!

> חכמים אומרים: אי אפשר לצמצם

So, how could G-d have created the world if *tzimtzum* is impossible?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Some fodder for an answer - R' Shimon Bar Yochai (author of Zohar) holds like R' Yosi Haglili that tzimtzum is possible.

Comment: Obviously, the world was not created. It is an illusion that we even exist.

Comment: @sabbahillel It is called Olam Hasheker

Comment: This is why one needs to believe in alternate dimensions. In one world it is shayach to be M'tzamztem . This world it's not

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly this can be answered from the first sugya in the gemara there.

> אמרי דבי רבי ינאי לרבי יוסי הגלילי שמעינן ליה דאמר אפשר לצמצם בידי שמים וכ''ש בידי אדם ורבנן בידי שמים אי אפשר לצמצם בידי אדם מאי

Now, although this initially seems to sound more impossible, being that we attribute more ability for tzimtzum to people than heaven, the fact of the matter is, this is not true.

What the sugya calls 'in the hands of heaven' are acts within nature such as the example there, an animal giving birth. What the sugya calls 'in the hands of man' refers to an act done with conscious intention.

Therefore Hashem's tzimitzum was certainly able to be performed. Firstly it was a conscious act. Secondly nature was not created yet so there was no 'in the hands of heaven' as referred to in the gemara.

Comment: And to think, _my_ question got you to 20k! Yashar koach!

Comment: Yiyasher kochacha!:)